# pass string from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I had tried to pass string from servlet to jsp .But it never forwarded to jsp .The following are the files

servlet file:

```
String login = "asd";
request.setAttribute("myname",login);
request.getRequestDispatcher("GetCategory.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

jsp file:

```
<% String name = (String)request.getAttribute("myname");
System.out.println(name);%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a bit rusty in that topic but i think i used the forwarding this way:

```
String nextJSP = "/searchResults.jsp";
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

So getting the RequestDispatcher from the ServletContext rather than from the request, but im not sure if there is any difference behind the scenes of both calls.

Edit: Where do you set that attribute? (Is it in one of the two Methods doGet/doPost?

Comment: I tried , but still have the same problem in .. line 2 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);

Comment: Have you tried the answer of ByteCode? (I am going to delte my answer if its not helpful within the next couple of hours)

Comment: i tried . but still facing the same problem

Comment: Can you try to add the following very simple example to your project and see if it works? http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/javaserver-pages/how-to-forward-requests-from-servlet-t.html

Comment: i set attribute in doGet

Comment: O.k. so that is not the problem, try to add the above simple example which should work. I unfortunately dont have time to try it myself right now :(

Comment: example works well .. thank you ...now i am trying to pass arraylist from jsp to servlet which contains object ...guide me to do that

Comment: I am trying like this...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766963/pass-arraylist-from-servlet-to-jsp

Comment: Once you can pass a String-Object to your JSP you can pass anything else to your JSP as well :) Glad i could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `out.println()`. `out` is [implicit object](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm) in jsp.

your code would be.

```
<% 
   String name = (String)request.getAttribute("myname");
   out.println(name);
%>
```

Comment: thank you for your comment . my problem is in servlet page . it doesnt forward to jsp page

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps place the jsp file inside the WEB-INF folder or somewhere inside it? if so then you should change it to
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/GetCategory.jsp").forward(request, response);