# Passing ArrayList from servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I am trying to pass ArrayList which contains object from servlet to JSP. But

Servlet file:

```
request.setAttribute("servletName", categoryList); //categorylist is an arraylist      contains object of class category  
getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/GetCategory.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

JSP file:

```
//category class    
<% Category category = new Category();
//creating arraylist object of type category class
ArrayList<Category> list = ArrayList<Category>();
//storing passed value from jsp
list = request.getAttribute("servletName");

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

category = list.get(i);

out.println( category.getId());

out.println(category.getName());

out.println(category.getMainCategoryId() );
}
%>
```

Comment: Why not use JSP-EL+JSTL to deal with the objects? Secondly, how are you getting from the Servlet to the JSP? using a redirect or a forward?

Comment: @DebojitSaikia the result displays nothing

Comment: @DaveG i am a beginner and am not aware of  JSP-EL+JSTL ... i am using following code to pass value in servlet ....      getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/GetCategory.jsp").forward(request,response);

Comment: @user2952188 try to get the dispatcher with `request` as `request.getRequestDispatcher('/jspFile.jsp').forward(request,response)`, and make sure servlet will DO NOTHING after it forwarded the request. in other word you are now allowed to use a request/response one it has redirected or forwarded.

Comment: @user2511414  actually it works well for passing string from servlet to jsp ..Is it needed to change to pass object ??

Comment: @user2952188 yes buddy it works, but the better(simple) way is using request. the `setAttribute()` method accepts `Object`, it means you would set anything.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the servlet code, with the instruction `request.setAttribute("servletName", categoryList)`, you save your list in the request object, and use the name "servletName" for refering it.
By the way, using then name "servletName" for a list is quite confusing, maybe it's better call it "list" or something similar:  `request.setAttribute("list", categoryList)`
Anyway, suppose you don't change your serlvet code, and store the list using the name "servletName". When you arrive to your JSP, it's necessary to retrieve the list from the request, and for that you just need the `request.getAttribute(...)` method.

```
<%  
// retrieve your list from the request, with casting 
ArrayList<Category> list = (ArrayList<Category>) request.getAttribute("servletName");

// print the information about every category of the list
for(Category category : list) {
    out.println(category.getId());
    out.println(category.getName());
    out.println(category.getMainCategoryId());
}
%>
```

Answer (score 6):

`request.getAttribute("servletName")` method will return `Object` that you need to cast to `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<Category> list =new ArrayList<Category>();
//storing passed value from jsp
list = (ArrayList<Category>)request.getAttribute("servletName");
```

Comment: you have forgot `new` before constructor `new ArrayList<Category>()` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <%

        ArrayList<Actor> list = new ArrayList<Actor>();
        list = (ArrayList<Actor>) request.getAttribute("actors");
    %>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Actor</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>This is Actor Class</h2>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                Actor actor = new Actor();
                actor = list.get(i);
                //out.println(actor.getId());
                //out.println(actor.getFirstname());
                //out.println(actor.getLastname());
            %>


            <tr>
                <td><%=actor.getId()%></td>
                <td><%=actor.getFirstname()%></td>
                <td><%=actor.getLastname()%></td>
               </tr>
            <%
            };
            %>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class myActorServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private String user;
    private String pass;
    private String given_table;
    private String tid;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String action;

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // connecting to database
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        name = request.getParameter("screenName");
        user = request.getParameter("username");
        pass = request.getParameter("password");
        tid = request.getParameter("tid");
        firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
        lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
        action = request.getParameter("action");
        given_table = request.getParameter("tableName");

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet JDBC</title>");
        out.println("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\">");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello, " + name + " </h1>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet JDBC</h1>");

        /////////////////////////
        // init connection object
        String sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM `" + given_table + "`";
        String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO `" + given_table + "`(`firstName`, `lastName`) VALUES ('" + firstname + "', '" + lastname + "')";
        String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE `" + given_table + "` SET `firstName`='" + firstname + "',`lastName`='" + lastname + "' WHERE `id`=" + tid + "";
        String sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM `" + given_table + "` WHERE `id` = '" + tid + "'";

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        out.println(
                "<p>Reading Table Data...Pass to JSP File...Okay<p>");

        ArrayList<Actor> list = new ArrayList<Actor>();
        // connecting to database
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javabase", user, pass);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlSelect);
            // displaying records

            while (rs.next()) {
                Actor actor = new Actor();
                actor.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                actor.setLastname(rs.getString("lastname"));
                actor.setFirstname(rs.getString("firstname"));
                list.add(actor);
            }
            request.setAttribute("actors", list);
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("myActors_1.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Servlet Could not display records.", e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ServletException("JDBC Driver not found.", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                    rs = null;
                }
                if (stmt != null) {
                    stmt.close();
                    stmt = null;
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                    con = null;
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
        out.println("</body></html>");

        out.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the possible errors would be...
1.you set the array list from the servelt in the session, not the in the request.
2.the array you set is null.
3.you redirect the page instead of forward it.

also you should not initialize the `list` and the `category`  in jsp. try this.

```
for(Category cx: ((ArrayList<Category>)request.getAttribute("servletName"))) {

out.println( cx.getId());

out.println(cx.getName());

out.println(cx.getMainCategoryId() );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

here list attribute name set in request `request.setAttribute("List",list);`
and `ArrayList list=new ArrayList();`

```
<%

ArrayList<Category> a=(ArrayList<Category>)request.getAttribute("List");

out.print(a);

for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)

{
    out.println(a.get(i));

}


%>
```

Comment: How does the jsp know about the class Category?