# Session Arrays in JSP

Tags: arrays, spring-boot, session

Can someone help me in making a array session in JSP? I want to add an item to the array in some part and later on access the whole value of item in my controller. I know how to do it on singular variables but i want to do it in array. Hoping someone can help me. Thank you so much.

I want to do something like

```
<%
    session.setAttribute( "theName[]", "sample name" );
%>
```

But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Do you mean to use list as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766963/passing-arraylist-from-servlet-to-jsp

Comment: yes but I want to access the list throughout the session.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [request.setAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766963/passing-arraylist-from-servlet-to-jsp), you can add Object using [setAttribute](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) and get it using `getAttribute`, e.g. JSP code:

```
List<String> sample = new ArrayList<>();
sample.add("1");
session.setAttribute( "sampleName",  sample);
```

And get it later in Controller

```
ArrayList<String> samples =  (ArrayList<String> sample)session.getAttribute("sampleName");
samples.get(0); // Use get/set to get/update array
```

Also if you meant to use `public java.lang.String[] getValueNames()` use `getAttributeNames()` instead

> **Deprecated.** As of Version 2.2, this method is replaced by getAttributeNames()

Comment: what is "sample" in (ArrayList<String> sample)